# PHP Require Stopped Working on Remote Server - No Errors or Warnings logged

Tags: php, apache, error-handling, require, remote-server

I was updating my website earlier and made some changes to `about.php` which has no includes and doesn't interact with other pages.

When I uploaded my changes however and tested the site, `contact.php` had stopped working, despite not being touched and working for months.

No errors are being logged despite `error_reporting(E_ALL);` being set which is making it very hard to debug.

I have found the cause of the error which is that the `require 'contactFunctions.php';` isn't working properly. I tested this on localhost and it works fine and just as it should.

I used the code below to test the require:

```
if((require 'contactFunctions.php') == 'OK')
    echo "Included";
else
    print_r(error_get_last());
```

This gives nothing. It's totally blank. The file is being found because if I change `contactFunctions.php` to something like `test.php` it will give errors about the require failing due to the file not being found.

Permissions all seem fine, it's never stopped working before, and it works fine on my local host.

Any ideas as to why it is not working or additional debugging methods I can go through would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: File is definitely being found

```
if(file_exists('contactFunctions.php))
    echo "Exists";
```

That works and outputs exists.

VERY WEIRD UPDATE:

Right so I contacted support but I haven't heard anything back yet.

I played around a bit and tried to use curl from my command line to submit an enquiry form...

It worked! The output displayed was the output that should display in the browser, but it doesn't work on any browser. There is no JavaScript involved and the HTML validates perfectly... Still incredibly confused.

Comment: Check if there's an "exit()" or "die()" inside the includedfile. Also, try with ini_set('display_errors', 1)

Comment: The file is fairly basic and just contains a few functions for processing messages. There are no exits or dies in the file. I will try ini_set now.

EDIT: Tried ini_set. Exactly the same issue. No errors

Comment: File not found, *hm...* - well on LINUX systems, `contactFunctions.php` is not the same as `contactfunctions.php`, check for letter-case.

Comment: Case is fine, the file is being found. That is what is so strange. It gives an error if I give a file that isn't there.

My local host is also Linux

Comment: You might have not set something in your `.ini` files related to error reporting. I've seen a similar question to yours a few weeks ago, and I couldn't find a proper solution for it then. But do look inside all your `.ini` files, if something is commented out, or should be modified. Remember to restart your system/Apache when changes are done.

Comment: test the syntax of your PHP files with "php -l file.php" (lowercase L)

Comment: No syntax errors detected in contact.php -- 
No syntax errors detected in contactFunctions.php

Comment: I can't modify the .ini files or restart the server as it's a remote server which I don't have appropriate permissions on. Calling support is an option but short of them disabling includes/requires (which is highly doubtful), I really don't see what it could be...

Comment: I would contact them and see what can be done about not seeing anything in the logs. Some hosts will let you upload `.ini` files (inside a particular folder) in order to override certain settings. I've done it before.

Comment: So do you even have access to the logs files to verify no errors were logged?

Comment: I do have access to the logs. I have tested the logs via missing semi colons, non-existant files, etc.